Join query producing Different Result for Select and Update Query (mariadb)
select t.pm_id,t.tc_pricelevels,t.oms_aplid, ' ' as sep, v.* 
from 
    temp_20240323_01_tallypl t  inner join 
    v_price_list_complete v 
    on  t.oms_aplid = v.price_list_id 
    and t.tc_pricelevels = v.price_level_name
    and t.pm_id = v.part_id

    where v.store_id =p_store_id
    and t.oms_aplid is not NULL
    and t.pm_id is not null     
    order by t.stockitem_name,tc_pricelevels

enter image description here
;-- ****************************
update 
    temp_20240323_01_tallypl t
inner join 
    v_price_list_complete v 
    on  t.oms_aplid = v.price_list_id 
    and t.tc_pricelevels = v.price_level_name
    and t.pm_id = v.part_id
       
set 
    t.discount_var = v.discount_var ,   
    t.oms_pricelist = v.pricelist,
    t.o_pricelist = 2000,
    t.oms_discount = v.discount_value,
    t.oms_rate =(v.pricelist * ((100-v.discount_value)/ 100))
where 
    v.store_id = p_store_id
    and t.pm_id is not null
    and t.oms_aplid is not NULL

enter image description here
value of oms_pricelist not as expected
Value of pricelist are 1975 and 2794 for Cost Price and Overseas for part no : 572052
but the result is unexpectdly 17777.

perhaps the 17777 rows have a different tc_pricelevels?  it would help if you showed just the columns being joined and the ones that are coming out wrong.

Thanks ysth. mariab mal-function in update query with multiple fileds join. To Over this Problem I used Subquery and problem is resolved.

highly unlikely this was a mariadb bug

Which table is p_store_id in??

p_store_id is param in procedure. and integer type field in price list
